# Is there such a thing as JSON schema for MongoDB query language itself?

Tags: json, mongodb, jsonschema

MongoDB queries--at least in JavaScript--are structured as JSON, but it's very flexible so I am aware this wouldn't be a simple thing to do and in fact not even sure if this is possible, but was just wondering.

Is there a JSON schema to detect if a random JSON is a valid MongoDB query object?

Comment: Note JSON schema is not a standard yet, just a draft.

Comment: You can perform schema validation during updates and insertions, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like [mongodb-language-model](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-language-model)

How to use

```
var accepts = require('mongodb-language-model').accepts;

console.log(accepts('{"ns":{"$in":["foo", "bar", "baz"]}}'));  // true
console.log(accepts('{"ns":{"$in":{}}}'));                     // false
console.log(accepts('{"ns":{"$regex": "foo"}}'));              // true
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the MongoDB Compass has (at least partly) implemented a Query Language verification for many commands like $or, $and $text / $search etc. Compass does not simply check if your query is a valid JSON, but also validates that you provided a correct query format.
If you are interested in how it has been implemented I would recommend you to check the github sourcecode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the following packages

[mongodb-language-model](https://github.com/mongodb-js/mongodb-language-model)

[mongodb-query-parser](https://github.com/mongodb-js/query-parser)

Answer (score 0):

You may validate that the structure is valid, but if you want to know if the query is actually correct, like has the right syntax and can be executed - then no, not really.